# Is it correct for me to print out pointers like this?

Tags: c, pointers

everyone! I am trying to understand pointers in C language. I wrote some code but I don't really understand what I am printing. I get my output like that:

```
10
-984409284
-984409284
-984409280
10
-984409280
-984409272
-984409284
10
-984409272
-984409264
-984409280
-984409284
10
```

Do you see that something's wrong with those? And also I get lots of warnings, don't know why.

```
cc     avr255.c   -o avr255
avr255.c: In function ‘main’:
avr255.c:9:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    9 |  printf("%i\n", &a);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int *
      |          %ls
avr255.c:10:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   10 |  printf("%i\n", p);
      |          ~^     ~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int *
      |          %ls
avr255.c:11:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   11 |  printf("%i\n", &p);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int **
avr255.c:13:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   13 |  printf("%i\n", q);
      |          ~^     ~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int **
avr255.c:14:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int ***’ [-Wformat=]
   14 |  printf("%i\n", &q);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int ***
avr255.c:15:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |  printf("%i\n", *q);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int *
      |          %ls
avr255.c:17:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int ***’ [-Wformat=]
   17 |  printf("%i\n", r);
      |          ~^     ~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int ***
avr255.c:18:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int ****’ [-Wformat=]
   18 |  printf("%i\n", &r);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int ****
avr255.c:19:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
   19 |  printf("%i\n", *r);
      |          ~^     ~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int **
avr255.c:20:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   20 |  printf("%i\n", *(*r));
      |          ~^     ~~~~~
      |           |     |
      |           int   int *
      |          %ls
```

This is my attempt code while understanding pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a=10;
        int *p=&a;
        int **q=&p;
        int ***r=&q;
        printf("%i\n", a);
        printf("%i\n", &a);
        printf("%i\n", p);
        printf("%i\n", &p);
        printf("%i\n", *p);
        printf("%i\n", q);
        printf("%i\n", &q);
        printf("%i\n", *q);
        printf("%i\n", *(*q));
        printf("%i\n", r);
        printf("%i\n", &r);
        printf("%i\n", *r);
        printf("%i\n", *(*r));
        printf("%i\n", *(*(*r)));
}
```

Comment: No, you must use `%p` to print a pointer, lkie `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);`

Comment: All variables have an address and a value. The address is where the variable is phisically stored, and the value is the content of this address. A Pointer is a variable that stores an address as value. You can get the address of a variable using & operator. You can obtain the content of a pointer variable using * operator.

Comment: Tip: `*(q)` is the same as `*q` and as such `*(*(q))` is just `**q`.

Comment: so, I should use `%p` with all the `*` ones? @WeatherVane

Comment: `printf("%i\n", *p);` is correct because the value is `int`.

Comment: okay, I changed all and warnings are gone except 2 of them. Warnings say `p` and `**r` 's placeholders should be `ls`. Why is that then can you also tell me?

Comment: A better question is, WHY do you want to print pointers? They are pointers, to a region of memory. Usually you are more interested into what the pointers points to than the actual pointer.

Comment: I just want to understand what is a pointer, how to define it etc @cmouse

Comment: @aicastell: A variable declared with `register` do not have an address, and an uninitialized variable does not have a value. (Note: Some people state that uninitialized objects take whatever value happens to already exist in the memory assigned to them, but this is incorrect. The C standard defines an uninitialized object to have an indeterminate value, meaning it is not required to behave as if it has any fixed value at all.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil the purpose of my answer was to provide information useful for someone with not too much experience developing, easy to understand. Uninitialized variables have a value ALWAYS, undefined, of course, but it has a value. Some compilers initialize undefined variables with zeros, but not all of them. Also, registers always have a value (defined or undefined). They don't have  an address in memory, right (so you can't get the address of a register variable with & operator). But I don't see any register variable defined in the initial question.

Comment: @aicastell: Re “Uninitialized variables have a value ALWAYS, undefined, of course, but it has a value”: No, it does not. Per C 2018 6.2.4 6 and 7, the value is said to be “indeterminate.” Per 3.19.2, this means the value is either “unspecified” or a trap representation. Per 3.19.3, for an “unspecified value,” the C standard “imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance.” This means the C standard permits `int x; printf("%d\n", x); printf("%d\n", x); printf("%d\n", x);” to print three different values; it is not required to behave as if `x` holds a value.

Comment: @aicastell: And, while such concepts may be difficult to explain to a beginner, you should not teach them a wrong concept. Doing so makes it harder to teach them the right concept later. They have to learn they are wrong, accept it, and learn new information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print an address of a variable:

```
int x = 7;
printf("%p", (void *) &x);
```

In order to print the address which is the **value** of a **pointer** variable:

```
int *xp = &x;
printf("%p", (void *) px);    // This line will print the address of x
```

In order to print the value of an int variable:

```
int x = 7;
printf("%d", x);
```

In order to print the value of the pointed address:

```
int *xp = &x;
printf("%d", *px);    // This line will print 7 as well
```

Comment: Note that `&x` and `px` have type `int*`, and `%p` requires `void*`. So type conversion with cast is required. For example `printf("%p", (void*)&x);`

Answer (score -1):

A pointer is what it says, an address to somewhere in memory. Example:

```
const char *ptr = malloc(10);
```

Now ptr holds the *address* to location with 10 bytes of memory allocated where you can
write things.

So you can do things like

```
ptr[0] = 'a';
```

And now the memory will contain character 'a' at start where ptr points to.

Usually the actual pointer is not very interesting, unless it's NULL (which is same as 0), which is often used to indicate unset value.